# What is the JSON equivalent of RSS?

Tags: xml, json, rss, feed, rss-reader

I need to publish feeds in my application, and I want to use a standard format like RSS. But my application data is in JSON, and I would rather not convert all my objects.

So is there a format that is equivalent to RSS but uses JSON?

Comment: No, but you can just use RSS inspired structure in your JSON.

Comment: Although there aren't any standard tools or libraries that'll deal with such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none. However, the great thing about RSS is that since it's a standard, you can use it as a "lingua franca" and let everyone convert it however they please :)